# How @Repository annotation works internally in spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on Spring project and there is a requirement to use stereotype annotations in project. I am trying understand how stereotype annotation @Repository works in Spring MVC application?

Comment: read about reflection?

Comment: @S.K. How does reflection help in my question . Could you please elaborate little bit.

Comment: *there is a requirement to use stereotype annotations in project*---what is this requirement based on? Is this a school project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With best of my knowledge using Aspect Concept.

You define your repository Interface (by extending JpaRepository & by Annotating @Repository).
Those interface(s) are picked up by the Application Context as Spring Beans. Then Proxy classes are created during runtime, using JDK Dynamic Proxy Library (or by CGLIB Library). 
Those Repository proxy classes have the implemented methods for the abstract methods you have defined. The implementations based on the definitions provided in the abstract methods. This happens during the Compile Time.

During runtime, whenever, the Repository methods are requested (Autowired), they are served by the respective Proxy Repository Class Methods.